# How can I simplify code in the foreach loop indexOF?

Tags: c#, foreach

I've a model with a lot of strings named "hours1, hours2, hours3... " which one is used to assign to the index of the foreach.
How can I simplify this code?

```
if (colNames.IndexOf(item2) == 0)
{
    if (model.Hours == null)
    {
        item.Hours = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        item.Hours = (decimal)model.Hours;

    }
}
if (colNames.IndexOf(item2) == 1)
{
    if (model.Hours1 == null)
    {
        item.Hours = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        item.Hours = (decimal)model.Hours1;
    }
}

if (colNames.IndexOf(item2) == 2)
{
    if (model.Hours2 == null)
    {
        item.Hours = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        item.Hours = (decimal)model.Hours2;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can always do `item.Hours = model.Hours1 ?? 0;` That'll take our one level of  if-else

Comment: @trailmax i made a correction to the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't very pretty, but perhaps:

```cs
decimal? hours = null;
switch(colNames.IndexOf(item2))
{
    case 0: hours = model.Hours; break;
    case 1: hours = model.Hours1; break;
    case 2: hours = model.Hours2; break;
}
item.Hours = hours ?? 0M;
```

Comment: thanks. can help with this? .... case 0:  item.Hours == null ? 0 : (decimal)model.Hours;